# MVC 5 in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have installed ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012 which has the MVC 5 templates for Visual Studio 2012. In Project Templates I am able to find the "ASP.NET MVC5 Empty Project" however after creating the Project, if I try to open the same project in the Internet Explorer by Pressing Ctrl+F5 it gives an error saying,

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

But When I create a MVC 4 Web Application and try to run it the Application works fine and shows the default page of the MVC 4 App.

Is there any other configuration needed to be done on the Visual Studio 2012 to make it run?

Comment: Everything is empty. you get only web.config file :)

Answer (score 2):

An Empty application is just that.  Empty.  There is no default page.  It's an empty project that you have to create the content for.

Microsoft did not supply a default application template for MVC5 in VS2012.  VS2013 does have a default template though.

Comment: I am new to asp.net, if you could suggest some good tutorial for this that could be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Sadanand - you would be better suited to just download VS2013 Express, which has the full templates

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an empty template it doesn't have a landing page and hence it was throwing the error

`Server Error in '/' Application.`

if you append the Controller name and view name just like below

```
localhost:port/[Controller]/[View]
```

It will show the contents of view.

Answer (score 0):

you can try either edit your routing.config file, or change your url. Usually it will default to index.

This is an example of a route you can maybe add in as a class, if you do not have one already. This controller just means that it defaults to the Home controller, at the action called index.

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

I hope this somewhat helps .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer is very succint, and it will probably help many readers who do not yet know how to do what you propose. Should you care to elaborate a bit further, or add a minimal example?